# wpf datagrid on click event

Tags: wpf

I use `datagrid` table on my project. One of the column of the `datagrid` is the path of the document according to my project. I would like to do that:

When the user clicks the path cell/hyperlink cell,

- Program will get the path,
- Program will open another tab.

I couldn't see the `onclick` event for the column, how can i do this? And also how can I switch the tabitems on the same wpf Window?

Hyper link column is that:

```
<toolkit:DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Path" Binding="{Binding path}" IsReadOnly="True" TargetName="{Binding Path=path}">
</toolkit:DataGridHyperlinkColumn >
```

Comment: There is no OnClick event, but there are MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp,MouseRightButtonDown, MouseRightButtonUp and the Preview versions of above events. I would suggest using one of the MouseUp events to substitute for the OnClick Event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Triggers?

you could define a trigger for the MouseClick event
and there set the other tab focus

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) into which you place a Textblock and Hyperlink.  This will provide a Click event. Here is a sample for defining a hyperlink column:

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Link Column" Width="125">
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Hyperlink Tag="{Binding TargetUrl}" Click="Url_Click">
                    <InlineUIContainer>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetText}"/>
                    </InlineUIContainer>
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Note that this was from a project using .Net 3.5 and WPF Toolkit. `dg` is defined in the XAML with `xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"`